# Excepción jaas.EmailValidator cannot be cast to javax.faces.validator.Validator

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Estoy intentando implementar un validador de email para una aplicación jsf y, a la hora de comprobar si funciona aparece esto y no me deja acceder al formulario ni tan siquiera:

> jaas.EmailValidator cannot be cast to javax.faces.validator.Validator
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: jaas.EmailValidator cannot be cast to
>   javax.faces.validator.Validator   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createValidator(ApplicationImpl.java:1587)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createValidator(ApplicationWrapper.java:507)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createValidator(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyAttachedObject(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyNested(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:224)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dejo el código:

**FORMULARIO**

```
<body>

    <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/Template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
          <h:form>

              <f:event listener="#{registerView.validarPassword}" type="postValidate" />
              <p:panel header="Crear una nueva cuenta">
                  <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="3">
                      <h:outputLabel for="nombre" value="Nombre:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText id="name" value="#{registerView.name}" required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Introduzca nombre y apellidos." maxlength="30"/>
                      <p:message for="name"/>
                      <h:outputLabel for="email" value="E-Mail:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText id="email" value="#{registerView.email}" required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Introduzca su email.">
                         <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator"/>

                      </p:inputText>
                      <p:message for="email"/>

                      <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Contraseña:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:password id="password" value="#{registerView.password}" feedback="true"
                                  required="true" requiredMessage="Introduzca su contraseña."
                                  validatorMessage="La contraseña debe contener al menos un número,
                                 así como caracteres tanto en mayúscula como en minúscula, además de 
                                 contar con una longitud comprendida entre 6 y 20 caracteres alfanuméricos">
                          <f:validateRegex pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})"/>
                      </p:password>
                      <p:message for="password"/>
                      <h:outputLabel for="confirmpassword" value="Confirmar contraseña:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:password id="confirmpassword" feedback="true"
                                  value="#{registerView.confirmPassword}" required="true"
                                  requiredMessage="Por favor, confirma tu contraseña."/>
                      <p:message for="confirmpassword"/>
                  </h:panelGrid>

                  <p:commandButton value="Registrarse" action="#{registerView.register}"/> 

              </p:panel>
          </h:form>

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

**VALIDADOR**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.PropertyException;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import javax.xml.bind.Validator;

@FacesValidator("emailValidator")

public class EmailValidator implements Validator {
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Zaz0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
private final Pattern pattern;
public EmailValidator() {
pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
}
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
if (value == null) {
return;
}
if (!pattern.matcher(value.toString()).matches()) {
throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error de validación", value + " no es un email válido."));
}
}

    @Override
    public void setEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler handler) throws JAXBException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationEventHandler getEventHandler() throws JAXBException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(Object subrootObj) throws JAXBException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateRoot(Object rootObj) throws JAXBException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(String name, Object value) throws PropertyException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) throws PropertyException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Estás implementando la interfaz incorrecta (import javax.xml.bind.Validator). La correcta es javax.faces.validator.Validator.

Comment: Cierto, no me había dado cuenta del detalle. Muchas gracias.